# Can someone help me understand those assembly lines?

Tags: assembly

can someone help me understand this for loop underneath written in assembly?

```
   0x08048d27 <+37>:    mov    $0x1, %ebx       //set ebx = 1
   0x08048d2c <+42>:    lea    -0x20(%ebp),%esi     //set esi to the address of the first element of the array
   0x08048d2f <+45>:    mov    -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax   //eax = esi + ebx * 4
   0x08048d33 <+49>:    sub    %ebx,%eax        //phase
   0x08048d35 <+51>:    cmp    %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)

   0x08048d38 <+54>:    je     0x8048d3f <phase_2+61>

   0x08048d3a <+56>:    call   0x8049108 <explode_bomb>

   0x08048d3f <+61>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x08048d42 <+64>:    cmp    $0x6,%ebx
   0x08048d45 <+67>:    jne    0x8048d2f <phase_2+45>
   0x08048d47 <+69>:    add    $0x30,%esp
   0x08048d4a <+72>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048d4b <+73>:    pop    %esi
   0x08048d4c <+74>:    pop    %ebp
```

I'm especially confused with "`mov -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax`" and "`cmp %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)`", what do these mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked for a reference on assembler syntax?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this version of assembly, but I can at least tell you that 0x30 != 30. The '0x' prefix means that the number is a hexadecimal (base 16) number, where you're familiar with decimal (base 10) numbers. 0x30 = 16*3 = 48

Comment: Oh Bomb Lab, have fun....

Comment: @Unn thanks! It's confusing tho I understand this look is asking for x, 4x-4, etc... for 6 numbers but I couldn't figure out the first number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov    -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
```

sets the value of `eax` to what's at `[esi + ebx*4 - 4]`

```
cmp    %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)
```

compares `eax` to what's at `[esi + ebx*4]`